# Синглтон Майерса и многопоточность

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, шаблон-одиночка

Не раз слышал фразу:

> После c++11 синглтон Майерса стал потокобезопасным...

Можете объяснить, почему такой код вдруг стал потокобезопасным?

```
class singleton
{
public:
    static singleton* instance() {
        static singleton inst;
        return &inst;
    }
private:
    singleton() {}
};
```

Comment: Стандарт гарантирует, что инициализация статического объекта может быть выполнена только одним потоком, другие будут ждать.

Comment: @ixSci, а можно цитатку из стандарта?
и есть ли минусы у такого подхода? раньше ж такого не было

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Это гарантируется стандартом, а именно *[stmt.dcl]p4*, стандарта C++17 (11 версии под рукой нет).

> Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage
>   duration (6.7.1) or thread storage duration (6.7.2) is performed the
>   first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is
>   considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization. If
>   the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization
>   is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control
>   enters the declaration. **If control enters the declaration concurrently
>   while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution
>   shall wait for completion of the initialization.** If control
>   re-enters the declaration recursively while the variable is being
>   initialized, the behavior is undefined.

Минусы подобного подхода мне не известны. Довольно удобный метод создания одиночки.

Comment: хм, спасибо... значит ничего интересного, просто в стандарт внесли и все, я думал там что-то более прикольное

Comment: Это появилось в стандарте С++17? В реализациях кода инициализации static в linaro g++ и llvm для c++03 я ничего подобного не видел

Comment: это появилось с 11 стандарта и компиляторы это поддерживают

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с с++11 компилятор стал явно добавлять блокировку, перед инициализаций статической переменной. Можете проверить на godbolt.org